# Show and hide pages in WordPress sidebar

Tags: wordpress, menu, themes

I am using WordPress 6.0.2 and the Twenty Twenty-Two theme to build my website. Now I've noticed that new pages I create are automatically added to the sidebar (header navigation).

Is there a way to control which pages are added to the sidebar and which are not? For example, I created an imprint that I only want to link in the footer.

Is there also a way to manage this directly from the database? I would like it too.

Comment: Try going to Appearance > Menus and see if there is an option named "Auto add pages". If you find it, then turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a WordPress made theme some settings can be enabled by default like auto add new pages to menu you can turn this off by going to customize > appearance > menus > and there should be a tick box that you can adjust to stop this from happening.

If this does not work go to the admin area which can be accessed by clicking the name of your website in the top black bar and head down to the appearance tab hover on it and click menus. This will allow you to edit specific menus with more options. If it is not there it may be a theme feature which you would need code for but i doubt you will need to go to this of an extreme.

Comment: The problem is that the Twenty-Two theme appears to have changed quite a bit. For example, the areas Appearance>Menus and Appearance>Widgets no longer exist in the admin interface. There must be some other solution, which I haven't found yet. That's why I also thought that it might be faster via the DB. In Twenty-One it was solved somehow more intuitively...

Comment: @altralaser ah i forgot WordPress added in full website editing into the 2022 theme!! Sorry about that. From what I can find natively there is not a way to stop this from being auto added into your menus by default however it is a simple process to remove them  here is a guide on a lot of different ways to edit it accordingly https://www.wpxpo.com/wordpress-menu-customization-in-twenty-twenty-two-theme/#Method_-1_How_to_Edit_WordPress_Menu_in_the_Twenty_Twenty-two_WordPress_Theme  I hope this helps From what I could see I also could not find any code to stop this sorry I could not be more help

Answer (score 0):

No need to access the database , just go to appearance > customize> menus . Here you will see several menus , choose the menu that is used or customize a new menu as you want .
The same thing goes for the footer , but to edit the footer you also need to go to appearance > widgets , then look at the right and you will see the footer columns you can also add/delete the footer from here .